# Create array dynamically with the name from another array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I need to create arrays dynamically.
Suppose I have an array

```
name = ['a','b','c']
```

each of this values will be an array with a fixed size.
like

```
a = [null, null, null]
b = [null, null, null]
c = [null, null, null]
```

Afterwards, I want to access each array with the value of name array. Like

name[0] will represent the 'a' array.

Comment: you can use `new Array(size)` syntax for this. 
But if you want to access it via key(name) you can use two approaches:
1. Set (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). 
And fill this Set dynamically.
2. Create an object and create fields dynamically via syntax: `obj[propertyName] = value(your array)`

Comment: I know this part. But how can I create the arrays??

Comment: something like that:
`const name = ['a','b','c'];
let arraysAggregator = {};
const fixedSize = 3;
name.forEach(key => {
arraysAggregator[key] = new Array(fixedSize);
});
//test
console.log(arraysAggregator['a'])
`

Comment: Maybe add the array name/arrays as key/values on an object and then `obj[name[0]]`?

Comment: you cannot dynamically replace the content of an array, you need to create a new array of arrays(in your case), the example how to do it as per you question, I provided as an answer.

Comment: @Skalpel02 you are a life savior. Thank you so much... :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const name = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arraysAggregator = {};
const fixedSize = 3;

name.forEach(key => {
  arraysAggregator[key] = new Array(fixedSize);
  //fill the content you need here
});

//test 
// access to an array as per key
console.log(arraysAggregator['a'])

// if you want to receive array of arrays you can use
const arrayOfArray = [...Object.values(arraysAggregator)];

console.log(arrayOfArray);
```

Comment: `new Array(fixedSize).fill(null)` would better suit the OPs output requirements.